# Why am I getting errors linking with Allegro 5.0.5

Tags: c++, g++, pkg-config, allegro5

http://pastebin.com/gL40jpHA

I don't have time to wrestle with stinking forum syntax when all I am trying to do is figure out a problem completely unrelated. All the information is in the pastebin. It was not letting me post it so I did it the EASY way.  I have been wrestling with this issue for hours.  Thank you to any who respond.

Comment: -1: `I don't have time to wrestle with stinking forum syntax when all I am trying to do is figure out a problem completely unrelated.` Then I guess we don't have time to help you with your problem. If you can't be bothered to post your stuff in the actual post, then why should we be bothered to help you with your problem?

Comment: that answer doesn't help, but thanks anyway

Comment: Your attitude stinks, wooden_dinosaur. There are reasons that we don't want a question that just contains a link and a rant, and it's mostly due to the fact that SO questions should be able to benefit some people other than just yourself. This isn't a personal support or debugging website. If you have no intention of respecting the way that SO works, then why are you posting on it expecting people to spend time helping you for free? I'm certainly not going to.

Comment: Also, **Stack Overflow is *not* a "forum"**.

Comment: Again, thank you for looking at the post.  I do not "expect" people to help me for free.  It is their option, as it is yours.  BUT, to post a question while giving as much information as possible for clarity for a first time user of the site, is frustrating.  Frustrating in that you cannot post unless the commands (which are perfectly readable in plain text) are formatted "just right".  I attempted the format several-several times and it only kept giving me the same formatting error when I attempted to correct it.  So I used an alternative approach for my first post.  As to the forum remark...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does `pkg-config --cflags --libs allegro-5.0` output ?

`pkg-config --cflags` on its own returns nothing because it isn't provided with the library to look up the custom CFLAGs and hence returns what CFLAGS is set which is nothing.

Try specifying the include and library directories explicitly .

What does `g++ -o foo allegtest.cpp  -I/usr/include -L/usr/lib -lallegro` output ?

Comment: The first command returns -lallegro  and the second gives me the same results as before.